# Android add view to fragment and bind adapters to views

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I'm playing around with fragments as of now, and I can't seem to find a solution to this issue..

This is what I have tried so far:

**FragmentReceivingStocksHeader.class**

```
    public class FragmentReceivingStocksHeader extends Fragment {

EditText etVanTransferDocument, etDocumentNumber;
Spinner spLocationFrom, spLocationTo;
Button btExit, btProcess;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFrom, adapterTo;
String[] locationsFromArray, locationsToArray;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    initControls();

    View rootView = 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receivingstocks_transactionheader, container, false);
    return rootView;



}

private void initControls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spLocationFrom = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spLocationFrom);
    spLocationFrom.setEnabled(false);
    spLocationTo = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spLocationTo);
    spLocationTo.setEnabled(false);

    locationsFromArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
    locationsToArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locationsto);

    adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsFromArray);
    adapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsToArray);

    spLocationFrom.setAdapter(adapterFrom);

    spLocationFrom.setSelection(1);

    spLocationTo.setAdapter(adapterTo);
    spLocationTo.setSelection(0); 
}
```

But I have errors on this line:

```
  spLocationFrom = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spLocationFrom);
```

**Error Message:**

```
   The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FragmentReceivingStocksHeader
```

And also these lines:

```
    adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsFromArray);
    adapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsToArray);
```

**Error Message:**

```
   The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentReceivingStocksHeader, int, String[]) is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong in here? I need your help guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initControls method, make the following modifications :

```
spLocationFrom = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.spLocationFrom);
spLocationTo = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.spLocationTo);
```

and

```
adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsFromArray);
adapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsToArray);
```

Explanation : findViewById is not available in Fragment like it is in Activity, so you need to use the View.findViewById method.
And the constructor or ArrayAdapter takes a Context as first argument, so Activity works but not Fragment.

Comment: Yes they are working fine.. I have another question, what if I'm gonna press the button or the spinner? Where will I put the onClick method?

Comment: Cool. As for your other question, your "initControls" method would be a good choice. But you need to remember that you cannot count on your Activity being fully created at that point, only in onActivityCreated can you safely assume that. So if you need anything from your Activity, I suggest you keep a reference to the views and assign the onClickListeners in onActivityCreated. More details here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Hi can you do some sample implementations of that?

Comment: You could have a look at this class : https://github.com/toodee/com.enlavertical.app/blob/master/EnLaVerticalapp/src/com/enlavertical/app/fragments/ExploreFragment.java It can always be a good idea to browse open source github repos for examples of implementations, like https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides or  https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that Fragment class doesnt have method like `findViewById`, like Activity does. You need to use your inflated `rootView.findViewById`.

As for your adapters, similarly, the constructor doesnt accept `Fragment` type, but `Context`.  `Activity` class extends `Context`, and you can access your activity from `Fragment` with `getActivity()` method.

See your code updated below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receivingstocks_transactionheader, container, false);
    initControls(rootView);
    return rootView;



}

private void initControls(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spLocationFrom = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.spLocationFrom);
    spLocationFrom.setEnabled(false);
    spLocationTo = (Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.spLocationTo);
    spLocationTo.setEnabled(false);

    locationsFromArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
    locationsToArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locationsto);

    adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsFromArray);
    adapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, locationsToArray);

    spLocationFrom.setAdapter(adapterFrom);

    spLocationFrom.setSelection(1);

    spLocationTo.setAdapter(adapterTo);
    spLocationTo.setSelection(0); 
}
```